# Heaven Can't Wait for The Angel And The Gambler

Tags: riddle, knowledge, music

> Soon you will be in another life, the twilight zone,
>   for I am a total eclipse and shall shatter your still life.
>   While you perceive the aftermath when two worlds collide,
>   I will still reap the book of souls for the greater good of god.

**Who am I?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are

> Iron Maiden band

The songs are hidden inside the title and riddle.

> **Heaven Can**'t **Wait** for **The Angel and the Gambler.**

---

> Soon you will be in **Another Life**, **The Twilight Zone**, for I am a **Total Eclipse** and shall shatter your **Still Life**. While you perceive **The Aftermath** when **Two Worlds Collide**, I will still reap the **Book of Souls**, **For the Greater Good of God**.

Comment: Isn't the title also three songs as well?

Comment: Title has two right? :)